# Debugging Google cloud messaging push messages

Tags: debugging, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push messages to an android application.
The POST https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send 
seems to succeed and I get something (with some numbers changed) like:

```
{"multicast_id":9999063399994069899,
 "success":1,
 "failure":0,
 "canonical_ids":0,
 "results":[{"message_id":"0:1416520599679103%8d7d198de508343a"}]}
```

but I don't seem to get the notification on the device...

Is there anything that can be done with the message_id it track it forward ?
Can I somehow tell me if Google actually tired to deliver it to the device and what was the result of the attempt?

Comment: If the message doesn't reach the device, there is a good chance the problem is in your app. You should post the relevant code + manifest. The GCM CCS protocol supports delivery acknowledgment, but GCM HTTP (which you are using) doesn't.

Comment: how is this relevant to my app? shouldn't a notification appear on the phone if the app is not running at all after initial registration?

Comment: the notification would only appear if your app is configured correctly and has the correct code for handling the message and showing a notification.

Comment: Are you sure?
because AFAIK the notification center should show a notification about the message when the app is not running. pressing the notification then launches the application. 
obviously I could be wrong. And another option is that we are both right and what I say is right for my environment (i.e when I am using the generic push plugin for phonegap build).
looks like I will have to look at the docs for the plugin again.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. When a message arrives, it reaches a BroadcastReceiver in your app (doesn't matter if the app is running or not), and it's your decision how your app will handle it (showing a notification that launches the app when clicked is a common behavior, but not mandatory).

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old question and you might have solved it yourself by now, but for completeness I would like to post a solution here.

By now you can find the option **GCM Diagnostics** in your Google Play Developer Console when you have your app selected. It's placed on the left hand side.

You just post a registration token or a message id and will shortly see a summary of push notifications connected to this token/id, plus additional debug information.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks - great answer.

Comment: Is this still in the dashboard? I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

well, at least until someone would provide a better answer about debugging based on message ids.

It turns out the problem in my case was that the phone gap plugin in I was using was expecting a "message" field in the push notification message payload. 
A bug on my server side made this message not to exist so it was not displayed in the phones notification area...

my thanks to @Eran for partially pushing my towards the right line of thought.