# Push Notification Diagnostics is no longer available from Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an older android app which is sending push notifications via legacy GCM.

I would like to diagnose particular push message without switching the messaging endpoint to Firebase messaging service.

If I undertand properly, [in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33016835/4606227) there was some screen in Google Play Developer Console named "GCM Diagnostics" which allowed to inspect each push message, but currently it seems this screen is gone, and the only option how to diagnose the push messages is to move to Firebase messaging service?

Comment: Are you positive you were accessing the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) instead of the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)?

Comment: AL - yes, I searched the Google Play Dev. Console for sure. So far I know the screen should have looked like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30717950/4606227

Comment: That is strange. Gonna go look around see if anyone else is encountering this. But seeing as there is still no announcement from Google, it was probably moved on a different part of the console (maybe a change in the UI like with generating a new API Key?).

Comment: I mean, if anyone can take look into his Google Play Developer Console  and will find there the "GCM Diagnostics", that is enough to persuade me that the service is still provided by Google (and it is just probably some configuration which prevents me from accessing it in for app)

Comment: @Peter even I am not able to find the GCM diagnostics options in play console